# Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'org.apache.commons.logging.b'

Tags: android, push-notification, proguard, android-proguard, pushy

My android app uses [Pushy.me](https://pushy.me/) Push notification service, i have built the signed apk with minifyEnabled true and when i run the app i am getting below error

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: The chosen LogFactory implementation does not extend LogFactory. Please check your configuration. (Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'org.apache.commons.logging.b'.
```

i have added below lines in proguard-rules.pro file, but it shows same error

```
-dontwarn me.pushy.**
-keep class me.pushy.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
`-keep class org.apache.** { *; }`